# Android delete from listview

Tags: android, listview, layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android Delete from listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032163/android-delete-from-listview)

This is my layout that suppot delete from listview ,the problem is when listview height is higher than screen height it goes under the button , so need a solution for avoding it